# How to format this date/time in javascript?

Tags: javascript

How do I convert

```
2018-05-07T17:51:17.258000-07:00
```

into:

```
May 7, 2018, 5:51 p.m.
```

using javascript.

I am completely new to javascript and cannot figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a library like Moment.js: https://momentjs.com/

```
const date = moment('018-05-07T17:51:17.258000-07:00').format('LLL');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use  [`Date#toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) with the options available in modern browsers.

Your desired format corresponds to the Canadian locale, which distinguish itself from the US one by adding the dots in "p.m." and putting "PM" in lowercase:

```js
var someDate = new Date();
var str = someDate.toLocaleString('en-CA', { 
    month: "long",
    day: "numeric",
    year: "numeric",
    hour: "numeric", 
    minute: "2-digit"
});

console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of options.

1. (easy) Use a JavaScript library

Check out https://momentjs.com
They have a .format method that is very easy to user

```
moment('2018-05-07T17:51:17').format('MMM DD, YYYY, h:mm a')
```

2. (easy) Use system date format

Instead of using a custom format, you could opt for using **.toLocaleString()** which will format the date towards the language settings of the machine it runs on.

```
new Date('2018-05-07T17:51:17').toLocaleString();
```

3. (complex) Write a custom format method in vanilla JavaScript.

JS itself is quite complicated when it comes to manipulating dates, but definitely possible. It's recommended to read the docs of all methods on the Date Object (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Date.prototype_Methods), because some might return a slightly different result than what you would expect if you're new to JavaScript.

Check out this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3graf72m/
I added some comments to explain what I did

```
const MONTHS = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];

document.body.innerHTML = getFormattedDate(new Date('2018-05-07T17:51:17'));

/**
 * Get the formatted date
 * @param {Date} date
 * @returns {String}
 */
function getFormattedDate(date) {
  const month = getMonthName(date);
  const day = getNumericDay(date);
  const year = getYear(date);

  let hour = (date.getHours() + 12) % 12;
  if (hour === 0) {
    hour = 12;
  }

  let minute = date.getMinutes();
  if (minute.length === 1) {
    minute = `0${minute}`;
  }

    const isAm = date.getHours() < 12;
  return `${month} ${day}, ${hour}:${minute} ${isAm ? 'a.m.' : 'p.m.'}`;
}

/**
 * Get the name of the month
 * @param {Date} date
 * @returns {String}
 */
function getMonthName(date) {
  // getMonth returns 0-based value
    const zeroBasedMonthInt = date.getMonth();
    return MONTHS[zeroBasedMonthInt];
}

/**
 * Get number value of the day of the month of a date
 * @param {Date} date
 * @returns {Number}
 */
function getNumericDay(date) {
  // .getDay returns zero-based day in week (starting from Sunday)
  // .getDate returns day of month (starting with 1)
    return date.getDate();
}

/**
 * Get the full year of a date
 * @param {Date} date
 * @returns {Number}
 */
function getYear(date) {
  // getYear returns year since 1900
    // getFullYear returns year (starting from 0)
    return date.getFullYear();
}
```

Comment: I added a fix now